# Need help figuring out how the paintComponent function works within javax.Swing

Tags: java

I'm creating a tetris program, and made a for loop that tells the program to create a 10x20 block structure, but I'm having trouble with actually painting the structure (I'm new to java).

I tried filling each block with the color of the block, with magenta if it is a border, black if nothing is there. When the time comes I'm going to assign each shape created a random color that will fill 4 spots in the array.

```java
public void start() {
            board = new Color[12][24];
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++) {
                    if (i == 0 || i == 11 || j == 22) {
                        board[i][j] = Color.MAGENTA;
                    } else {
                        board[i][j] = Color.BLACK;
                    }
                }
            }
            newPiece();
        }
    @Override 
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            // Paint the well
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 26*12, 26*23);
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 23; j++) {
                    g.setColor(board[i][j]);
                    g.fillRect(26*i, 26*j, 25, 25);
                }
            }
```

I expected for there to be a 10x20 box to show up with magenta background and black boxes but only the top left border is rendered before the code fails.

Comment: What happens when the code "fails"?  If there are error messages, copy the full text and paste it here.

Comment: Your [fillRect](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,int,int,int%29) parameters seem strange.  Do you really want to paint a 2×25 pixel rectangle, at increments of 1 pixel across and/or down?  I don’t know of any Tetris variant that looks like that… (Also, the first line of code in a paintComponent method must be `super.paintComponent(g);` or you will see strange visual artifacts.)

Comment: @VGR - Yea im very new to Java Swing, thats my bad, I just updated the code to reflect that the pixels are now 25x25, do the first two parameters in fillRect tell the program how far apart each rectangle is on the x and y axis? thank you for your help by the way.

Comment: Please follow NormR’s advice, and add the full stack trace of any exception you’re getting to your question.

Comment: @NormR Before my issue was that I couldn't get anything to show up on my screen, that was due to the pixel size. It was just a logistical error that showed up. Now however, the top border of my screen is cut off. I'm not sure if I incorrectly formatted it within my main method or not.